# How do I tell if my OpenVPN connection is working?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

On my old server, I had it set up with the Private Internet Access application, and I was able to determine the connection with `nmcli con` command, and I would see something like "PIA - US West" or something similar to determine my connection.

With my new server, I am headless and configured via OpenVPN. `nmcli con` outputs the following:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE
Wired connection 1  000000-000-00000-00000-000000  802-3-ethernet  enp2s0
tun0                111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111  tun             tun0
tun1                222222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222  tun             tun1
```

Why are there two instances tun0 and tun1? How can I be sure my OpenVPN is functioning properly?

Answer (score 1):

Check your IP before and after enabling the VPN, if the IP is different, then the VPN should be working. You can check your IP with:

```
echo "Your IP: $(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
```

Comment: So my IP shows my location and ISP when I reverse searched it. Isn't tun0 and tun1 showing that the VPN is active though?

Comment: Try without the VPN, and then with the VPN and check if the IP is different

Comment: @therza you can see what route it takes with ```ip route get 208.67.222.222```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Google and ask "What is my IP", it will tell you the public IP.  If you disconnect and it's the same, then you were not connected.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo ifconfig -a

this link should help https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN#Test_VPN